How to Change the default color of <input type="color">?
I'm using Angular and want to change the default color of an <input type="color"> element. Currently, it shows black (#000) as the default, but I want to set it to a different color. How can I achieve this?
Also,
I'm using Angular v18.
I've tried setting the value attribute, but it doesn't work.
My code snippet:
<input type="color" name="color" value="#ff0000" ngModel />


<input type="color" name="color" [(ngModel)]="selectedColor" value="#ff0000" />

export class AppComponent {
  selectedColor: string = '#ff0000';  // default color red
}


You should use either use [value] or [(ngModel)] but not both together, that is causing the bug.
    <input type="color" name="color" [(ngModel)]="model"/>
    <input type="color" name="color" [value]="model"/>

Full Code:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule],
  template: `
    <input type="color" name="color" [(ngModel)]="model"/>
    <input type="color" name="color" [value]="model"/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  model = '#ff0000';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
